# add folder path to System ClassLoader

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, resourcebundle

How can I add a folder to the System ClassLoader classpath so my TOMCAT app find resources?

inside a jar file from a 3rd party lib I have resource been loaded by the code

```
String resourceName = "MyResource";    
ResourceBundle RESOURCE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(resourceName, Locale.getDefault(), ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

in this folder I have the resources

```
/opt/properties/
     MyResource.properties
     MyResource_en.properties
     MyResource_en_US.properties
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/opt/properties` to the `common.loader` property of `/conf/catalina.properties` file.

Code you posted looks correct to load it, should work with that property in place

Comment: dont know what's happening but i'm still getting  java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name MyResource, locale en_US :?

Comment: You already restart Tomcat after changing the properties file?

Comment: yes, tried to run from eclipse editing the catalina.properties on ide and from command line and the common.loader looks like  D:\\opt\\properties,/opt/properties,${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar

Comment: Try it without specifying the ClassLoader: `ResourceBundle RESOURCE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(resourceName, Locale.getDefault());`

Comment: I cant, it's a code from a 3rd party. I decompiled the jar to reach this code.

Comment: I can do a test. Maybe is something with security policy.

Comment: Yeah that was my next guess; `/opt/*` should be accessible but worth checking.

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394570/java-jre-7u45-breaks-classloader-getresources

Comment: maybe, this is a security lib from an app that I'm rebuilding the environment with no documentation. The class that call the resource is a signed class in production. I'm preparing the code to work on dev without the secret part. This System ClassLoader is doing some trick